# React/RCTBridgeModule.h file not found RNSSplashScreen

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, splash-screen

When configuring React Native Splash Screen i get the following Error 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found.  I have looked at solutions online but i have not managed to find a clear solution.

I have tried a few solutions online, and i have gone over the steps in the Splash screen documentation but to no avail.  The error appears in RNSplashScreen.h

[image]

I am using React native 6.0+

Comment: I have added "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/react-native-splash-screen" to my Header search paths in build settings but to no avail.

Comment: I have also tired deleting my podfile and reinstalling

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you get it resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ npm i react-native-splash-screen --save
$ cd ./ios
$ pod update
You don't need to do react-native link on XCode 11 beta + RN >= 0.60
And 'Do Not' add the libSplashScreen.a library to Link Binary With Libraries since this will cause the 'Duplicate Symbol Error'.
And go to AppDelegate.m and import the header as follows
#import <react-native-splash-screen/RNSplashScreen.h>
instead of
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"
```

Obtained from the following Link

https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/215